# Database Design for Asset Management

Tags: database, database-design

I'm developing an Asset management application.

Looking through the excel tracker that was being used previously, I was able to identify some attributes that were common to all categories of assets (basically non-technical attributes such as `Purchase Order No`. , `Warranty Info` etc.) for which I think I will make a separate table.

But when storing technical-attributes, there are many categories of assets for which I need only one or two additional attributes to be stored.

Should a make a single table for all these attributes and store NULLs wherever applicable or should I make a separate table each category containing just the asset ID and the addition columns?  Which approach is better/more pragmatic?

Is cluttering the database with too many tables ok? I have around 10 such categories.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are 3 known approaches to this:

**Single table**

In this model, you have a single table with all known columns, and allow them to be null for types that don't have that attribute. This gives you a simple database, and fairly simple SQL, but doesn't allow support for common features that relational databases give you, like insisting on non-null columns for a data type, or creating unique indices where that makes sense.

It also tends to lead to messy SQL, with developers forgetting over time what columns mean, so you could get a column being used for multiple purposes.

It does make it easy to join to other tables - so if you have an asset and a purchase related to that asset, the "purchase" table joins to the "asset" table on "assetID".

**Table per subtype**

In this case, you build a table for each subtype, and enforce the data characteristics of that subtype with not null, unique etc.

This creates a clearer separation of subtypes, and is less likely to degrade into big ball of mud, but makes joins very hard - to join from "purchase" to "asset", you have to know which table holds that particular asset.

**Common table for common fields, table per subtype**

In this model, you have a single table for the fields that are common between subtypes - you say you've identified this already - and have further tables for each subtype to store the unique attributes.

This solves the joining problem between "asset" and "purchase", keeps the data pretty self-describing.

It does mean client logic needs to implement the "join asset_master to asset_subtype" issue.

I prefer option 3 - it's the best trade-off between maintainability and managability.

Comment: thanks for the elaborate answer. I've separated the common attributes already and luckily half of the assets do not need any additional attributes to be stored. I've clubbed servers, desktops and laptops under 'computers' and for remaining i've a table called 'others' which has about 8 columns.

Answer (score 1):

Databases should be able to handle lots of columns and lots of tables, so both approaches should work from that perspective.

If you don't have any additional requirements, I'd use the single table approach. It is the easiest, and the only thing you are loosing is the ability to put not null constraints on the fields that exist only form some categories